# How to adjust the position of several axes in one chart?

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I create a line chart using dojo. Recently, I have been applying multiple axis on the chart. But there was a problem here. It is applied to multiple axes in one place I have raised the issue of overlapping tick value. and do not change the properties of leftBottom, is there a way to adjust the shaft position? For example, x: 10, y: 20?

my code

```
 var axisXRef = {labels : labelsample, titleOrientation : "away", stroke : {}, natural : true};
 var axisYRef = {vertical : true, stroke : {}};

 var chart = new Chart("chartNode");
 chart.addPlot("lines", { type: Lines, tension: 3 ,min:0});
 chart.addPlot("stacklines", { type: StackedLines, tension: 3 ,hAxis:"x",vAxis:"y1"});
 chart.addPlot("areas", { type: Areas, tension: 3,hAxis:"x",vAxis:"y2" });

 chart.custom.axisX = lang.clone(axisXRef);
 chart.custom.axisY = lang.clone(axisYRef);
 chart.addAxis("x", chart.custom.axisX);
 chart.addAxis("y", chart.custom.axisY);
 chart.addAxis("y1", {
                vertical: true,
                min : 50,
                max:70,
                leftBottom:true,
                majorLabels: true, majorTicks: true, majorTick: {color:"red",length:50},
                minorLabels: true, minorTicks:true, minorTick:{color:"red",length:50},
                microTicks: true, microTick:{color:"red",length:50},
                fixUpper: "major",
                fixLower:"minor"
           });
chart.addAxis("y2", {
                vertical: true,
                min : 0,
                max:49,
                leftBottom:true,
                majorLabels: true, majorTicks: true, majorTick: {color:"blue",length:25},
                minorLabels: true, minorTicks:true, minorTick:{color:"blue",length:25},
                microTicks: true, microTick:{color:"blue",length:25},
                fixUpper: "major",
                fixLower:"minor"
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Dojo charting only supports two axis per direction both axis being on different side of the chart. In other words you can't have two axis both on the left side of the chart. You have to have one right side using leftBottom: false property.